# Originally I planted flowers for you to digest. What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This is my first puzzle, so please be gentle! Came up with the idea on a drive home and thought it was neat, so I'd like to share it and see if it's as tricky as I hoped.

> Originally I planted flowers for you to digest
>
> Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead
>
> I often prevail on the battlefield
>
> But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

What am I?

Hint #1:

> The answer is an abstract noun.

Hint #2:

> Lines 1 and 2 are quite closely related.

Cryptic hint:

> Look between the incisor and premolar. Nowhere will Muriel show you a brave one.

Edit: I've added a bit to the cryptic hint which should make the answer clearer.

Comment: @AJ Do you mean the first line of the riddle or the first hint I gave?

Comment: the first line of the riddle

Comment: "Originally" in the first line relates to the same thing as "later" in the second line, and also involves a colour.

Comment: @JohnClifford Don't put the answer in the question. Others may come across your riddle and want to try to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Dan, I didn't think of that. I'll keep it in mind for any future riddles I post.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is it

> Cowardice?

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> Before cowards were referred to as "yellow-bellied", they were known as "lily-livered". Lily is a flower, the liver is part of the digestive system. - thanks to the problem poser for this answer.

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> Yellow belly is term used to describe cowardice

I often prevail on the battlefield

> Often prevails in war.

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> cowardly soldiers won't often be victorious.

Hint:

> Muriel has a dog (canine) called "courage the cowardly dog".

Comment: Dingdingding! We have a winner! Cowardice is the correct answer. Do you want me to just explain the first line or are you still thinking about it?

Comment: Yes, please do explain.

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense! Thanks for that! I'll edit it into the accepted answer

Comment: No worries! Hope you enjoyed my first puzzle. :)

Comment: Aw Nice!  Kicking myself!  The Cryptic hint was mean John!  Cool though...  +1

Comment: "Originally I planted flowers for you to digest" this could mean also the *agricultural revolution*. Where our ancestors chose a more safe and stable life of farming, as opposed to the risky life of a hunter gatherer.

Answer (score 5):

ANSWER ONE:

> The color red

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> Red roses/Apples

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> The stomach is red

I often prevail on the battlefield

> Blood

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> The bloody army is losing/Red card in soccer, when a player gets thrown out of the game? Or this could be anger, as in 'seeing red' - being angry often makes you lose judgement and lose.

ANSWER TWO:

> Blood

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> ????

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> The stomach is red with blood

I often prevail on the battlefield

> Bloody battles

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> Again, the bloody army is losing

Answer 3:

> A smart mouth

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> Flattering, buttering up

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> When you get angry your stomach turns red

I often prevail on the battlefield

> A smart mouth can win battles?

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> Just having a smart mouth doesn't mean you always win - it can often get you in trouble in sports.

Comment: +1 for a well-thought-out answer, but not quite! You're not far off with your interpretation of the last line.

Comment: @JohnClifford see my edit.

Comment: When I said your last answer wasn't far-off it was still logically not quite where I'm looking. Here's a hint: the answer is an abstract noun.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Guts

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> I'm not sure about this

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> the intestine or the lower alimentary canal or a part of this

I often prevail on the battlefield

> Many warriors show guts in battlefield

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> Can't say

If you look between the incisor and premolar, you'll find a brave one.

> The Canine, used for tearing things. Carnivorous have a large Canine to tear/gut animals they hunt.

Comment: Oddly enough, your answer is close in sentiment but on the wrong end. Well done on mostly getting the cryptic hint, but you're thinking of it too literally. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a strong answer but...

> Iodine?

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> It is important in nutrition and is added to fertilizers used in fruit farming

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> It is used as a dye in medical examinations

I often prevail on the battlefield

> It has antiseptic properties

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> Well... You probably couldn't use it as an effective weapon and if you need it you're probably loosing already?

**OR could it be**

> Iron?

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> iron tools

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> iron in the blood makes the blood red

I often prevail on the battlefield

> Iron weaponry

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> Philosophical maybe?

Comment: Wow, both good answers but not the one I'm looking for. Keep trying! Would a hint be useful at this point?

Comment: I imagine so, yes :)

Comment: I'll add a couple to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> The colour yellow?

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> Not sure...

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> Yellow belly?

I often prevail on the battlefield

> Yellow, as in fear, often prevails in war.

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> Fearful soldiers won't often be victorious.

Comment: You're incredibly close with your logic but your answer isn't right. Think about something similar to #2 that can also be applied to #1, and what the last two lines represent.

Comment: Gutted now I've seen the answer...  Great puzzle though!

Answer (score 3):

Ok.  So how about-

> Green?

Originally I planted flowers for you to digest

> Green fingers / green thumb?

Later I decided to colour in your stomach instead

> Eating your greens?

I often prevail on the battlefield

> Money can win wars?

But I've rarely carried my team to victory.

> And... I have no idea.

Comment: It isn't a colour, your interpretation of the second line was closer in your last guess.

Comment: Darn.  Ok.  Thinking cap!